# Center table in Header - Cognos 10

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I used a table for a header with 3 columns, aligned left, center, and right. The columns are not even, so the center column does not look centered (left and right aligned are fine).

The left column has a text box "Client Office: " + upper (ParamDisplayValue)".
The center column has a text box with "Pipeline Fees (Office)"
The right column has a text box "As Of: " + Date + " - " + Time

How can I get the three cells to have the same width so that my center cell shows correctly.

Newbie with Cognos, so not sure how to manipulate html, etc. or even if the environment at this company allows it.

TIA

EDIT: I think the reason this is an issue is that the header cells correspond to cells in the report body. There are 12 data items returned, so each header cell spans 4 body cells. The width of the first four columns is wider than any of the next four (dimensional attributes in the first four, metrics in the others), so the first header cell is wider than the other cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need a table inside the header. Here's what you need to do:

Select the header. Then, under `Structure > Headers & Footers`, select `Split List Row Cell`. That should make it match the columns in the list.  Then, if you want to make a header cell span multiple cells in your list, you can select the header cells and merge them.